# Householder reflector application

Tags: matrices

How would I apply the Householder reflector matrix in order to zero the first column of a matrix A, then the second column and the third and so on?
Has anyone had any experience applying it and can show me the steps?

[image]

Comment: See p. 4-1 of this [document](https://cpb-us-e1.wpmucdn.com/blogs.rice.edu/dist/8/4754/files/2016/09/caam453-26jhhu3.pdf)

Comment: Hmmm... but how do i design the Household reflector to zero between row 2 to max row or between row 3 and max row of a target column vector?

Comment: Thank you Jean Marie, is this type of Mathematics considered deep i do not see tutorials on it on youtube?